# Return Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I want to return a multiply dimensional array from a function like so but I must be writing it wrong, I cant figure out whats wrong. I want to have `key` and `value` pairs.

```
function Multidimensional(){

    return [ 
        "one": [
            "two":[],
            "three":[
                "testing.png":{source:"http..."}
            ],
        "another.png": {source:"http..."}
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have key/value pairs, you should use [an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

```
function Multidimensional(){

    return { 
        "one": {
            "two":[],
            "three":{
                "testing.png":{source:"http..."}
            },
        "another.png": {source:"http..."}
    };
}
```

You can access the returned data like so:

```
var data = Multidimensional();
console.log(data['another.png']);
// or
console.log(data.one);
```

Comment: Ok but when i'm looping true the object how can I determine witch one has a source/end from one that's a hierarchy?